# c#/Arduino SerialPort.read() is empty

Tags: c#, arduino

I am trying to retrive some data from my arduino

I am using this on my arduino:

```
Serial.println((String)animation);
```

and this in my c# application

```
log.WriteEntry(message, EventLogEntryType.Information);

port.Write(message.Replace(Environment.NewLine, ""));

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

port.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer).Replace("\0", "");

log.WriteEntry(message, EventLogEntryType.Information);
```

I also tried it by using `.ReadTo(NewLine thing);` and `.ReadLine();`

my message always looks like this: [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cv5tr.png)

Comment: Unfortunately, casting an integer (or whatever the type of `animation` is) to a string won't actually produce the textual representation. Try `Serial.println(animation)` or `Serial.println(String(animation));`